# URL amigavel com TimThumb

Tags: php, htaccess

Hoje, eu uso essa regra pra criar URL amigavel e usar MVC nos meus projetos:

```
RewRiteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

No caso, eu uso o TimThumb pra gerar imagens em cache, no PHP, e ele me retorna uma URL, por exemplo:

> https://meusite.com/tim.php?src=https://meusite.com/uploads/images/2018/02/post-de-teste.png&w=560&h=230

Como eu faria, no caso, pra usar o mesmo com URL amigável também? Eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, seria também no HTACCESS?

Comment: Sim. Com a regra que você colocou, você redireciona todas as requisições para o arquivo `index.php`. Se quer que determinada requisição seja tratada por um arquivo diferente, tal como `tim.php`, você deverá criar a regra para tal.

Comment: Pensando aqui, acho que não vai dar por conta dos tamanhos dinâmicos que a imagem precisa :(